# Does Azure AD User provisioning SCIM supports /bulk operations?

Tags: azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim

Does Azure AD registered Enterprise Applications for User provisioning supports /bulk operation.
They have listed the enpoint in their [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#table-4-determine-the-endpoints-that-you-would-like-to-develop).
But, On registering application, I didn't find any option calling this bulk operation.

I found one more link related to this, but even the question is unanswered there. [check this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/39018394-user-provisioning-optimized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Kindly go through the below [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/43996/does-azure-ad-support-bulk-usergroup-provisioning.html), which answers your question directly from the product team.